# Spring 3 @value annotation with maven profile properties

Tags: java, spring, maven, properties, annotations

I have a bunch of properties defined in pom.xml for different profiles. I would like to use @value annotation to inject the property values. It is enough to get the values set at build time.

What kind of options I have with this @value annotation? Do I have to have a separate property file or can I utilize applicationContext.xml?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I'd do is use the [properties maven plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/) to [write the project properties to a file](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/write-project-properties-mojo.html) and then reference that file from Spring via [the `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer` mechanism](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer)

Comment: @CupawnTae yeah, spring changed their doc server a while back. many old answers have erroneous links. And codehaus died recently. I'll try to fix the links

Comment: thanks - would normally have chased them down myself but was in a hurry, so just thought I'd at least flag it

Answer (score 1):

The Maven filtering works as a simple textual substitution, it doesn't know anything about spring and annotations. Not sure which way is better for you, if you describe your problem (but not one of yours possible solutions), I could try to suggest more constructive solution.